# "invalid data source name" with PDO MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, ini

It was always working for me but this time it's not.

conect.ini

```
conn = "mysql:host=localhost; dbname=%dbname%"
user = "root"
pass = "%passwd%"
conn1 = "mysql:host=%myRealHostAddr%; dbname=%dbname%"
user1 = "%user%"
pass1 = "%passwd%"
```

pdo

```
class prepeared {
    const LOG = "lock/loginsStat.log";
    private $_db;
    private $dbc;

    function __construct(){
        $this->dbc = parse_ini_file($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/hours/lock/conect.ini");
        try{
            $this->_db = new PDO($this->dbc["conn"], $this->dbc["user"], $this->dbc["pass"]);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

etc....
Vars %var% are real values just changed them for this post. 
Vars with 1 are working at the hosting just fine (without 1, it was added only for a local testing). When I take it to a local machine for some testing I'm adding this 1 to disable them and making a new vars for a local settings.

The error that I see now it's

> invalid data source name

Any ideas why? I know that this configuration was working just fine when I used it couple weeks ago so I suspect there is no errors here. Probably I'm wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get rid of `catch(PDOException $e){ echo $e->getMessage();}` stuff in order to get **full** and useful error message instead of that stub you have at the moment.
2. `var_dump($this->dbc);` also helps a lot.

Comment: OK the problem was in the $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/hours/lock/conect.ini" It was a wrong way. Thank you so much for your help.